# a class wrapper functions in typescript

Tags: typescript

Here is my class:

```js
class Foo {
  static actions = ["func1", "func2"];
  a: number;
  func1(str: string) {
  };
  func2(n: number) {
  };
  func3() {}
}
```

My goal is to make the proper typescript annotations of a generic function (the `wrapIt` function below) that takes any class (like `Foo`, with a random set of properties and functions) and returns a class that implements only the given actions from the static fields `actions`:

```js
function wrapIt(MyClass) {
  return class {
    constructor() {
      for (const actionName of MyClass.actions) {
        const fn = MyClass.prototype[actionName];
        this[actionName] = (...args: any[]) => {
          console.log("do something here that just call the original function");
          return fn.bind(this)(...args);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const NewClass = wrapIt(Foo)

const c = new NewClass();
c.func1("ok"); // typescript error: func1 is not known
```

`func1` and `func2` of `Result` would probably be the original `func1` and `func2` but wrapped with some code

I don't have difficulties to do that sort of code in pure JavaScript, but in Typescript, it's hell for me :-|

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoa0IBcw4EthoxhD4A7GAXmgG0AiAMwFcLgBGBgGmmbeAAmBgF0A3BixgAXNAosAtgCMApgCcJmaK3YcAFLjWzDBCgHMAlCknQAvpqw6heirPnL1VtFvs2nAZj0vWwwQ9AwncgpoAHc1MAAHAEkcPQBZAE8AYXAoLxs1FRwWNWjQSBhvLCxgSkMWMng1IOstau0m6D1aqhwSMgJKADkwBRVoeCZoTJyKgDpSKIh8tvboHtxtaNoZ3Ig5hLV4HGOMhJU6RcGKEbHxGzXoHAALAghLgeHRlRFoWj05oCwGozBBZGAKBk6CIrNQAHytR7tDbwEAqOYgeBmPQMAAmSAg8DGL1MZmgz3U4xe%20GgACsWJtgGAQCAnhSJmoCGZTMztAIogwLA4kVhCsVSls5kpTLi9CTlgCgSDlsLHmE1Q87DYwmEMBs%20kMVDFZlA-rF4slUgh4BYMHq6n1iLQKEboIbjXsgppgHMnPoGPAANaCsRAA)

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make `actions` a compile-time constant in `Foo` by adding `as const`:

```typescript
class Foo {
    // ...
    static actions = ["func1", "func2"] as const;
    // ...                             ^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Then we can do it with generic type parameters on `wrapIt`. First let's define a reusable type for a constructor function:

```typescript
type ConstructorFunction = new (...args: any[]) => any;
```

Now we need to define the type of the `wrapIt` parameter. It needs to be:

- A constructor function
- With an `actions` property which is an array of valid method names

We'll need the method names as its own type parameter. To restrict them, we need the to extend `keyof` the type of object created by the constructor, which we can get via the utility type [`InstanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype). That looks like this:

```typescript
function wrapIt<Cls extends ConstructorFunction, Method extends keyof InstanceType<Cls>>(
    MyClass: Cls & { actions: readonly Method[] }
) {
    // ...
}
```

(I haven't actually limited `actions` to only *method* names there, just instance property names. You can take it further if you don't want the user to put `"a"` in `actions`, but I haven't bothered with that here. I've included a note on how to do it below, though.)

Now to the return type. With those two generic parameters and the [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) utility type, the return type is relatively simple: `Pick<InstanceType<Cls>, Method>`. Let's define that as something we can use in more than one place:

```typescript
type WrapItReturn<Cls extends ConstructorFunction, Method extends keyof InstanceType<Cls>> = new (
    ...args: any
) => Pick<InstanceType<Cls>, Method>;
```

Then we use `WrapItReturn<Cls, method>` as the return type (only, we could let TypeScript infer it, but let's be explicit) and as a type assertion on what we're returning:

```typescript
function wrapIt<Cls extends ConstructorFunction, Method extends keyof InstanceType<Cls>>(
    MyClass: Cls & { actions: readonly Method[] }
): WrapItReturn<Cls, Method> {
    return class {
        constructor() {
            for (const actionName of MyClass.actions) {
                const fn = MyClass.prototype[actionName];
                (this as any)[actionName] = (...args: any[]) => {
                    console.log("do something here that just call the original function");
                    return fn.call(this, ...args); // Minor implementation tweak here
                };
            }
        }
    } as WrapItReturn<Cls, Method>;
}
```

Here's that all together:

```typescript
type ConstructorFunction = new (...args: any[]) => any;

class Foo {
    static actions = ["func1", "func2"] as const;
    a!: number; // Added the ! just to avoid irrelevant initialization error, not part of solution
    func1(str: string) {
        console.log(str);
    }
    func2(n: number) {
        console.log(n);
    }
    func3() {}
}

type WrapItReturn<Cls extends ConstructorFunction, Method extends keyof InstanceType<Cls>> = new (
    ...args: any
) => Pick<InstanceType<Cls>, Method>;

function wrapIt<Cls extends ConstructorFunction, Method extends keyof InstanceType<Cls>>(
    MyClass: Cls & { actions: readonly Method[] }
): WrapItReturn<Cls, Method> {
    return class {
        constructor() {
            for (const actionName of MyClass.actions) {
                const fn = MyClass.prototype[actionName];
                (this as any)[actionName] = (...args: any[]) => {
                    console.log("do something here that just call the original function");
                    return fn.call(this, ...args); // Minor implementation tweak here
                };
            }
        }
    } as WrapItReturn<Cls, Method>;
}

const NewClass = wrapIt(Foo);

const c = new NewClass();
c.func1("ok"); // typescript error: func1 is not known
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oGLoLYCWiUAvFAhAO5QAUAdMwIaoDmSAXFCwiAG0AugEoKAPl78A3AChZmADYskSKHjhwoAb1lR9UFC2DFMvEojWUBAIgBmhTAEYbAGij3HAJhtDeazEtgOQNeAEIeBHQAWwAjCFRpKAB6ZKgAQQATTIhMqGAAC2gwqAArdBR8rRYANzhiPOJUVAhFCBq+YChiBGITFkViAC9jUgQoBNRcdwQ4LrA2Lrg7QzhFdBNEPQMHIid6FFQeQ572MV1Q0MDkNYhGRTh2A7QREIMAX239XcwvegRIjF4qhzl9LtckLd7o9-q8wZ9Qj8AMz0c6fT6yUCQKAAdVQLDAAElgAAlCDAdCoBAAHhgijUEAAHsAIAhMmp4Mg0FgcPhHJsEO4ALLkgpwPJMllstQAawgIGWUEJXL4mAgABVwBBafTxJJKNQ6PQwcxGGxODw+CBZGJyJIAAqmGXU5VGIgarU6pDiYWi8XiOSyH4CqA0fFE4BeibM1ns2BBDDYXAEIgC32FcXRqVxuUKlau4Cqj2QL1642hIUgOkqbiwelQABkOnMAtrLRYmUQihAUBFGcywignxEPDxBOJZIpVK96bFmUkFwMLSn4yUNZ0YKuCZ5uFRG8uB6gdlwDAhXRYFgQADkWNFoIrK9XVGbL0hQYeP1Az0fxpRH8pnzAKYcCxCABAvAUbzvIQ3k-S56EKYg1BUKQQBEcDLygiA-EoJhWA4WsrWEW0F03ODwUsKEHieGxO1WO9EIQdgoCKFp8gKYwygqLpMAGRR2PvVBiHYHoBiPfkxhsOFyM-ZdKXGOwEEYXjFEUBCCiQ9xTXNN8klSXsehPYhojANo7wQQsQ2AGgIBYGUWISCAyLg95YM-BFDw8-R3n8XFwwncl5JnXs-XnOQMW-K9aCfKxQ384B6A0OA4QUIIvwoKhaCgKKaBi1E5EwRgfn2Gw4BlKS9LSUCkEwISwC6SZcB4YrujUWYuhlWYaAQIA)

---

If you want to restrict the contents of `actions` to the keys of *methods* only, you can use this utility type:

```typescript
type FunctionKeys<ObjType> = keyof {
    [Key in keyof ObjType as ObjType[Key] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? Key : never]: Key;
};
```

Then use `FunctionKeys<InstanceType<Cls>>` instead of `keyof InstanceType<Cls>`:

```typescript
type WrapItReturn<Cls extends ConstructorFunction, Method extends FunctionKeys<InstanceType<Cls>>> = new (
    ...args: any
) => Pick<InstanceType<Cls>, Method>;

function wrapIt<Cls extends ConstructorFunction, Method extends FunctionKeys<InstanceType<Cls>>>(
    MyClass: Cls & { actions: readonly Method[] }
): WrapItReturn<Cls, Method> {
    // ...
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oGLoLYCWiUAvFAhAO5QAUAdMwIaoDmSAXFCwiAG0AugEoKAPl78A3AChZmADYskSKHjhwoAb1lR9UFC2DFMvEojWUBAIgBmhTAEYbAGij3HAJhtDeazEtgOQNeAEIeBHQAWwAjCFRpKAB6ZKgAQQATTIhMqGAAC2gwqAArdBR8rRYANzhiPOJUVAhFCBq+YChiBGITFkViAC9jUgQoBNRcdwQ4LrA2Lrg7QzhFdBNEPQMHIid6FFQeQ572MV1Q0MDkNYhGRTh2A7QREIMAX239XcwvegRIjF4qhzl9LtckLd7o9-q8wZ9Qj8AMz0c6fT6yUCQdSOTYIADSEBASAAPAB5WKlAAq4AgkkoAGsicsdGCBISQN1xkyQCyKdTaf4oPyaZB2US-BAAB7ACAITJqJisDjcKSCUQSNVQAD8UA5UEi7QSQh4HLk7zkmMFAHVUCwwABJYAAJQgwHQqAQJJgijU0tl8rU8GQaCwOHwuLG7gAsm6CnA8v65QqcUQ8RzSQ6Q3xMBBRRBvb7xMWKFRaAwwcxGGxODw+CBZGJyJIAAqmBkkrNGIh52mFpDiGNxhPiS0-PFQGh2x3AfsTGXJoNBDDYXAENNRqCxwoJ+cBlPriwEomZ7M9-P94viehg6MgH0qVU+tQAMh05jxqpaLEyiEUnO3eNMmEKBPhEHhbXtJ1XXdT1+yHHdMkkC4DBaWDxiUR9WUuAwIVDVdUFRbCcMuOxcAYPCPzGAA5FhomgFk7wfVRqyPJBQRIzioEouxxkoJjlBYsAphwLEIAEFgj1o+ihDeLjLnoQpiDUFQ1RECSpLoiA-EoJVqxVOt+GEJtkLBeScIhKEHieGxf1WeilIQdgoCKFp8gKYwygqLpMAGRR3IY1BiHYHoBigccxhsOFzK4tCPXGXjGF8xRFEUgplPcKsa3YpJUi3HpyOIaIwDaeiEGAUYyGAGgIBYBkXISCAzPMi1mpwhESI6-R3iFSCZxg+L4K3YckPNeRKOo2hmKsSdpydegNDgOEFCCbjS2oOhJpoabUTkTBGB+fYbDgBkotytIxKQTAgrALpJlwHhDu6NRZi6BlZhoBBZCAA)

In that, if you add `"a"` to `actions`, you'll see that `Foo` is no longer a valid argument for `wrapIt`, since a non-function property is listed in `actions`.